# Qt Imgur upload fail

Tags: qt, base64, imgur

I have an uploader like this

```
void uploader::upload() {
    QUrl serviceUrl = QUrl("http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json");
    QByteArray postData;

    postData.append("key=MY_KEY&");
    postData.append("image=" + file.toBase64());

    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    networkManager->post(QNetworkRequest(serviceUrl), postData);
}

void uploader::serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply* reply) {
    qDebug() << "Done" << endl;
    QString response = reply->readAll();

    qDebug() << response;

    QScriptValue sc; 
    QScriptEngine engine;
    sc = engine.evaluate(response);

    qDebug() << sc.property("upload").property("links").property("original").toString();
}
```

file is QByteArray with PNG file content which i want to upload.
When uploading ends, I receive the response, but uploaded image is not valid (if i save it and trying to open, it writes that the file is not valid PNG image).

What I'm doing wrong?